# ArcGIS Pro - How to put grid coordinates on two different lines in layout?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, grids-graticules

I'm new to ArcGIS Pro and I am a bit confused on how to add a customised coordinate grid in layout.

I can add a default grid, but I cant find any way to customise it.

I want to create a grid [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUemL.jpg)

How do I do it?

Comment: Please use the Picture button to include images in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a similar look using the black mixed vertical label grid.
[image]

- In the labels, I added a carriage return between the two parts of the dynamic text, to split the number.
- Changed the vertical to North, South.

[image]

- Lengthened the ticks
- Removed the internal grid.
- Added a rectangle around the outside as an outer neat line

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed your instructions and it is almost perfect! Thanks. 

[Map layout](https://imgur.com/a/DiuyBZR)

By any chance do you know how to make both rows of coordinates centred and equal in size?

Comment: Read up on [formatting text tags](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm) and [grid label tags](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/grid-label-tags.htm).
To change where the text is split look at the _digits_ tag in the measured grids.
To make the text the same size, remove the _font_ FNT over-ride.
If it worked click on the accept answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the help!